# Condition variable vs mutex in C++ std

Tags: c++, synchronization

I do not understand the difference between a condition variable and a mutex. In my opinion, it's not described clearly enough.

Can someone explain it independently of any programming language? And a C++ std specific explanation as well?

Comment: maybe it would help if you explain how you think they are the same, because it isnt that obvious (i dont see it)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 at least in std, both put threads in a blocking state to avoid race conditions, and wake a thread up when the critical section has finished executing.

Comment: A mutex is just what its name indicates: a mutually exclusive locking mechanic. A condition variable is a signalling mechanic. Together, in conjunction with some sort of predicate data (a flag, a counter, some.. "state") which the mutex protects at *all* times (never check, nor change, predicate data without the mutex latched by the current thread), they form a powerful tool in concurrent program architecture. TL;DR, condition variables are used to signal state-change in predicate data, mutexes provide exclusive access to that data. The former is designed to work in harmony with the latter.

Answer (score 3):

The use cases are rather different. Mutexes are very primitive, they merely make sure that only one thread can have a lock on it. Condition variables let you model more complex situations, as any thread can signal the blocked thread to continue.

Typical situations are:

Bathroom: You want to make sure that only one person can use it at any time. When the person enters it locks the door and leaves it open when finished. That would be a mutex.

Production chain: Several workers produce item A and worker W needs that item to produce item B. Whenever one worker finished an item A, they put it in the queue and signal to worker W, that they can continue to work on B. That would be a condition variable (condition being: item A is available).

Answer (score 2):

With mutexes and locks you normally put the thread to sleep until mutex is unlocked. (Or if it is unlocked, you simply lock it and continue without all the sleep part).

With condition variable you put the thread to sleep until it is asked to wake up and proceed (via `notify_one` and `notify_all` methods) - normally you are advised add a condition to wake up, that thread verifies upon being notified.